# PHPMyAdmin incredibly slow

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Does anyone else's phpmyadmin take an incredibly long time to load? like 68 seconds after i click a table it finally gets there...!

its also very slow when i click the "add data from text file into table" button...

is there anything that can be done to speed it up?

Comment: We'd need to know a lot more about your setup before attempting to answer this–can you provide that?

Comment: I did a fresh install of the whole server, this time i could use this solution because i did not have any valuable data. Thanks!

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/14351073/470749. Paste these lines into the bottom of your config.inc.php file within your phpMyAdmin installation: `//http://future500.nl/phpmyadmin-slow-on-startup/:` `$cfg['MaxExactCountViews'] = 0;//disable trying to count the number of rows in any view`
`$cfg['MaxExactCount'] = 0;//disable correcting the InnoDB estimates`
Thank you to future500.nl! I wish I'd found this fix hours earlier, before I accidentally deleted all my data.  :-(

Comment: Since this is pretty high on the Google results, I figured I'd share a solution that worked for me: in the config.inc.php try changing the "host" value from "localhost" to "127.0.0.1". This saved 90% of the page load time for me.

Answer (score 2):

Are these slow tables under any kind of access from other applications?  If the tables are being placed under an explicit read lock that could be blocking phpmyadmin.  There could be an implicit lock by a large insert going on as well.

If it's taking that long you should be easily able to run a show processlist from a straight command prompt to see if you PMA user is sitting locked, sending data, nor maybe nothing at all on the database side.

Comment: `SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST` see https://stackoverflow.com/q/3638689/1066234